# $e^x=1+(x-a)+\frac{(x-a)^2}{2!}+\ldots$ for every $x,a\in \mathbb R$

Tags: calculus

This is a simple question. The Taylor series for the exponential function at $a$ is

$$e^x=1+(x-a)+\frac{(x-a)^2}{2!}+\cdots$$

Let's take for example $a=0$ and $a=3$, if we prove the remainder of the Taylor polynomial $R_{0,k}(x)\to 0$ and $R_{3,k}(x)\to 0$ when the order $k\to \infty$ can I say:

$e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\ldots=1+(x-3)+\frac{(x-3)^2}{2!}+\ldots$

for every $x\in \mathbb R$?

Comment: What happens when $x=a$? You get $e^a=1$ for all $a$. This can't be right. :)

Comment: @ZacharySelk So the remainder $R_{a,k}(x)\to 0$ when $k\to \infty$ only for $a=0$? in another words, the Taylor series coincides with the exponential function only at $a=0$?

Answer (score 5):

This is actually slightly wrong.  Note that

$$e^y=1+y+\frac{y^2}{2!}+\frac{y^3}{3!}+\dots$$

Let $y=x-a$,

$$e^{x-a}=1+(x-a)+\frac{(x-a)^2}{2!}+\frac{(x-a)^3}{3!}+\dots$$

Lastly, multiply both sides by $e^a$ and we have

$$e^x=e^a\left(1+(x-a)+\frac{(x-a)^2}{2!}+\frac{(x-a)^3}{3!}+\dots\right)$$

Comment: So the remainder $R_{a,k}(x)\to 0$ when $k\to \infty$ only for $a=0$? in another words, the Taylor series coincides with the exponential function only at $a=0$?

Comment: @user42912 Clearly yes, since your series is not actually equal to $e^x$.

Comment: I was mistaken, $1+(x-3)+\frac{(x-3)^2}{2!}+\ldots$ is not the Taylor series of the exponential function at $a=3$.

Answer (score 3):

Your series sums to $e^{x-a}$.

The Taylor series for $f(x)$ at $a$ is
$$
f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+\frac{f''(a)}{2!}(x-a)^2+\dotsb
$$
(provided it is convergent in a neighborhood of $a$). For $f(x)=e^x$,
$$
e^x=e^a+e^a(x-a)+\frac{e^a}{2!}(x-a)^2+\dotsb
$$
owing to the fact that $f^{(n)}(a)=e^a$.